# How to enable JavaScript Protractor Firefox headless

Tags: javascript, firefox, protractor, e2e-testing

We have e2e test with Protractor on headless mode.

We want to test the authentication first. 
The behaviour is like the above:

1/ The user tap a link on the browser
2/ the server will check if this user is authenticated or not
2.1 if the user is authenticated, the home page will appear
2.2 if not, the user will be redirect to the sso login page by a

The problem here is that, the javascript won't be executed. I try to add some flags but it doesn't make any difference.

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    specs: [
        './e2e/account/**/account.spec.ts',
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'marionette': true,  
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
          args: [ "--headless"],
          firefox_binary: '/opt/firefox/firefox',
          binary_: '/opt/firefox/firefox',
         },
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
   },

    directConnect: true,

    baseUrl: 'http://demop-staging-ppd.com/',
    framework: 'mocha',

    // SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    mochaOpts: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        slow: 3000,
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 720000
    },

    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
        // Disable animations
        // @ts-ignore
        browser.executeScript('document.body.className += " notransition";');
        const chai = require('chai');
        const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        const chaiString = require('chai-string');
        chai.use(chaiString);
        // @ts-ignore
        global.chai = chai;
    },

    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

the spec file :

```
  before(async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);    
  });

  it('should content display content ', async () => {
    await browser.get('/');
    browser.sleep(5000);
    const content= await browser.getPageSource();
console.log(content)

  });
```

I'm open to any suggestions and can provide you with any additional information.

[UPDATE]

I change my config file as a above to try enabling javascript on my browse. It works on local but when I try this on docker image dosen't

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'marionette': true,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ["--headless"],
            firefox_binary: '/opt/firefox/firefox',
            binary_: '/opt/firefox/firefox',
            "prefs": {
                "javascript.options.showInConsole": true,
                "javascript.enabled": true
            },
            "log": { "level": "trace" }
        },
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,

      },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
multiCapabilities: [ { browserName: 'firefox', firefoxOptions: { args: ['--headless'] }, 'moz:firefoxOptions': { args: [ '--headless' ] } } ]
```

Please check with this

Use `webdriver-manager` to execute. With `directConnect` you will have permission denied error.

I checked in linux PC also. This works fine

[image]

Comment: I tried the multicapabilities script and that doesn't work. I am wondering, why the directConnect will cause a permission denied. I do not have this error appear.

Comment: Try adding '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1000x1000' in your args

Comment: I using the exact config in windows. Let me try in Linux PC and update you.